# How to include an Spezial character in a bash curl statement

Tags: bash

I try to run this command in a bash script, but I always get errors.

if I do this manually it works

```
/usr/bin/curl -u :cbftp -s -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d '{"command": "site search test", "sites": ["homeftp"]}' --insecure | tail -n +6 | head -n -3
```

the output is:

```
{
"failures": [],
"successes": [
{
  "name": "homeftp",
  "result": "200- Found 1 entries in index (limit 50):\r\n200- /home/user/test\r\n200 Search complete\r\n"
}
```

]

so it is in the script

```
#!/bin/bash
search=$1
ftp=$2
gosearch=$(/usr/bin/curl -u :cbftp -s -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d '{\"command\": \"site search $search\", \"sites\": [\"$ftp\"]}' --insecure | tail -n +6 | head -n -3)
echo "$gosearch"
```

so i get the error:

```
{
"error": "[json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 2: syntax error while parsing object key - invalid literal; last read: '{\\'; expected string literal"
}
```

I suspect it is a special character that should not be used

I want the output like this:

```
  "result": "200- Found 1 entries in index (limit 50):\r\n200- /home/user/test\r\n200 Search complete\r\n"
```

Comment: did you missed `=`  or space after `gosearch` ?

Comment: hm, only copy paste fail, it still doesn't work

Comment: any variable inside SINGLE quotes will NOT expand. Meaning `$ftp` will be considered as literal string `$ftp`. Use double quotes

Comment: change your line to `gosearch=$(/usr/bin/curl -u :cbftp -s -X POST https://localhost:55477/raw -d "{\"command\": \"site search $search\", \"sites\": [\"$ftp\"]}" --insecure | tail -n +6 | head -n -3)`

Comment: ah thx, working perfekt

Comment: nop, its not my question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape double quotes if you put them in single quote strings.